# How to fix button on display

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

I'm a pretty newbie in (swift) programming so I hope you can forgive me if I phrase or ask something stupid.

I have a `ViewController` with a `ScrollView`. I fill the `ScrollView` with different content, like a `TableView` and ImageViews. Next, I would like to add a button. This button should be in the lower right corner of the display, no matter where the user scrolls down or up. Can you give me some guidance? Basically, I'm looking for a property that will allow me to reference the edge of the display.

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

Comment: I have tried your solution, unfortunately it does not work. Or did I understand you wrong? (See screenshot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, friend you have to set your button outside scrollView layer .

- you can do this in Canvas(storyboard or xib file) make sure its above scrollView layer
- the easy way adde with code like this:

  ```
  let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
  let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 45.0

  let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
  let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 200.0

  let padding:CGFloat = 30.0

  let customframe = CGRect(x:(screenWidth - buttonWidth - padding) , y: (screenHeight - buttonHeight - padding), width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
  let floatingButton = UIButton(frame: customframe)
  floatingButton.backgroundColor = .blue
  self.view.addSubview(floatingButton)
  self.view.bringSubviewToFront(floatingButton)
  ```

make sure you add your button to self.view  and call bringSubViewToFront after, this will to as it sounds but you have to add your layer first to do somthing.

- no matter how many layers you have, or having scrollView. this will work on all and all iphone sizes

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Have you tried this?When I try to slide the button over the ScollView, it automatically slides back behind the ScrollView. 

I edited my post and built an example in the storyboard (image shown in link). Button 2 should be fixed.

Comment: Worked for me: `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(floatingButton)`

Comment: @anuri in your storyboard check your button it shouldn't be under scrollView hierarchy , they should be in the same lavel. when your button becomes part of scrollView it will move!

Comment: Hey, I did. I put them on the same level.

Comment: images says it's wrong . but if you are sure check that your button constraint  only related to main view of view controller

Comment: Yes, I’m sure. I took the screenshot before trying out a solution to clarify my problem better.

Comment: let us check the problem , when you try to change the location of button iin storyboard it goes the wrong place?  try moving it with right menu(property inspector) only select the button from hirarecy and change x&y from right menu

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you have your view (you could put your code, that would help the question more), on the contrary, what occurs to me in the way of integrating a button, is to use the JJFloatingActionButton pod and it allows you to have a floating button in your view.
Visit https://cocoapods.org/pods/JJFloatingActionButton for more info about this library.

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the storyboard. Button 2 should be fixed. Button 1 moves in the scrollview as it should. Hope you can understand me better now. Unfortunately the suggested CocoaPod is not what I am looking for.